# How to cast or convert List of objects to queue of objects

Tags: c#, object, queue, generic-list

How can one convert a list of objects to a queue thereby maintaining the same order?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`Queue` has a constructor that takes in an `ICollection`. You can pass your list into the queue to initialize it with the same elements:

```
var queue = new Queue<T>(list);    // where 'T' is the lists data type.
```

Comment: Good catch. There actually is a non-generic Queue, but you'd likely want the generic version. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @zerkms: There is a non-generic `Queue` class in the `System.Collections` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx

Comment: But now that you've updated your code example to use `Queue<T>`, your remark that the constructor takes an `ICollection` is no longer accurate (the `Queue<T>` constructor takes an `IEnumerable<T>`).

Answer (score 10):

What do you mean by "the same order?"

If you do this:

```
var queue = new Queue<object>(list);
```

Then the queue will be enumerated over in the same order as the list, which means that a call to `Dequeue` would return the element that had previously resided at `list[0]`.

If you do this:

```
var queue = new Queue<object>(list.AsEnumerable().Reverse());
```

Then the queue will be enumerated over in the opposite order as the list, which means that a call to `Dequeue` would return the element that had previously resided at `list[list.Count - 1]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var q = new Queue<Object>();
for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ ) q.Enqueue( list[i] );
```

That is, assuming "same order" means that the first item to be dequeued from the queue should be list[0].

If it means the opposite, just use the reverse loop: `for( int i = list.Count-1; i >= 0; i-- )`

Answer (score 3):

Add this extension to your toolbox to create a FIFO queue of the specific type.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static Queue<T> ToQueue<T>(this List<T> items) => new Queue<T>(items);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var mylist = new List<int> {1,2,3};
var q = new Queue<int>(mylist);
```