# Convert List to Queue c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

is it possible to convert a List  to a Queue  element??
Until now i used the code below but adding an extra loop is not necessary if there is a build up method in c#

```
queue1.Clear();

foreach (int val in list1)
{
     queue1.Enqueue(val);
}
```

any solution?

Comment: There's a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`, but thats O(n) too. I've checked the source, but it doesn't reserve space based on `ICollection<T>` though.

Comment: Actually, depending on where `queue1` has come from could really affect this (have retracted my dupe close vote because of this).  If it's a parameter to a function for example, you can't just assign it to a `new Queue`.  You'd have to clear/reload it etc.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`Queue<T>` has an [overload which takes an `IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69zckb8z(v=vs.110).aspx). Note it will iterate it anyway:

```
var queue = new Queue<string>(myStringList);
```

This is what it does internally:

```
public Queue(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    _array = new T[_DefaultCapacity];
    _size = 0;
    _version = 0;

    using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) 
    {
        while(en.MoveNext()) {
            Enqueue(en.Current);
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463675/how-to-cast-covert-list-of-objects-to-queue-of-objects