# Cast LinkedList<int> to Queue<int>

Tags: casting, queue

I have an assignment where I'm required to create a queue and fill it with consecutive integers.  Another requirement of the assignment is that when I construct a Queue object, I must allocate a new LinkedList, but store it in a Queue variable.

The sample code below illustrates the above in my constructor.  It fails to compile because of the following error:

> Error CS0030  Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue'

Can someone please propose the changes I need to make in my constructor to initialize these variables?  Include an additional example how I'd "add" an item to the queue as well please.

..........................

```
class Sieve
{
    public Queue<int> qSource;
    public Queue<int> qPrime;

    public Sieve()
    {
        qSource = (Queue<int>)new LinkedList<int>();
        qPrime = (Queue<int>)new LinkedList<int>();
    }

    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

---

The assignment verbatim outlines the following requirement:

"...You must use a Queue interface. When you construct a Queue object, allocate a new LinkedList, but store it in a Queue variable. The LinkedList class implements the Queue interface. Both should be imported
from java.util. For example:

Queue myQueue = new LinkedList();

..."

Do note that I'm doing the assignment in C# yet it was handed out as a Java assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast/ covert List of objects to queue of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463675/how-to-cast-covert-list-of-objects-to-queue-of-objects)

Comment: "when I construct a Queue object, I must allocate a new LinkedList, but store it in a Queue variable" - that makes absolutely no sense!

Comment: @KenY-N.  I edited my post and appended the text verbatim from the assignment indicating that I must use the Queue interface to store a list of numbers but initialize as follows:

Queue myQueue = new LinkedList();

Thanks for your review though.

Comment: I see; this is OK for Java as [LinkedList has a Queue interface](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/the-interface-and-class-hierarchy-for-collections/), but for C#, [Queue and LinkedList only share an IEnumerable](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/oop-csharp/html/notes/collections-slide-collection-overview-1.html), which offers no insert capability, so what you are trying to do is basically impossible, IMO.