# Cannot convert implicitly Linked List to Queue

Tags: c#

When I am trying to convert Linked List to Queue I am getting following error

```
Queue<String> oldList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: A `Queue` is  not a `LinkedList` and vice-versa. You need to convert from one to another yourself.

Comment: Well, its telling you the issue. There is no implicit conversion from Queue to LinkedList. Perhaps this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463675/how-to-cast-convert-list-of-objects-to-queue-of-objects

Comment: What did you *expect* to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could create a `Queue` via [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69zckb8z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
LinkedList<string> linkedList = ....

Queue<String> oldList = new Queue<string>(linkedList);
```